# Source of method call python

Tags: python, oop

How can I check if the call it made from with in a class or outside of class?
e.g.

```
class Test:

    def dog(self):
        #Call from inside of the class
        self.cat()

    def cat(self):
        #how to check if call is made from inside the class or outside?
        return

#Call from outside of the class
Test().cat()
```

P.S. Without importing anything.

Comment: You don't it shouldn't make any difference to the flow of your program, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a different output when the call is from inside the class.

Comment: That really doesn't make any sense, and you're just opening yourself up (or worse, someone else) to a world of debugging hell. Just have your `dog` function process the return from the function differently

Comment: You will eventually create a `Test` object that would call `dog()` and then inside `dog()` method you wish to call `self.cat()`. Am i getting it right?

Comment: you could create a new class inheriting the original and override the the method

Comment: Basically, when the call is made from inside the class, I want only part of cat method to be execute. That is all.

Comment: Do you know the [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? I wouldn't advise to try to check if it's called from inside the class or from outside of it. That probably involves checking the stacklevels and is definetly overkill for something that should be (and could be easily) solved by another approach.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, when the call is made from inside the class, I want only part of cat method to be execute. That is all.

This sounds like your function is doing too much then, you'd be better off splitting it into separate functions

```
def dog(self):
    #Call from inside of the class
    pet_cat()
    chase_cat()

def cat(self):
    feed_cat()
    pet_cat()
    chase_cat()
    return

def feed_cat():
    pass
def pet_cat():
    pass
def chase_cat():
    pass
```

In answer to your direct question, you can't only run part of the method - its a bad idea and all possible options allowing you to do this are all dirty hacks

Answer (score 0):

Without importing, just pass the caller as parameter:

```
class Test():
    def dog():
        self.cat(self)
    def cat(caller=None):
        if caller == self:
            print "inner call"
        else:
            print "outside call"
```